# silverlight autocomplete against async wcf service

Tags: wcf, silverlight, asynchronous, autocomplete

I'm working in Silverlight 5 and am trying to write an autocomplete textbox (I'm using the telerik radwatermarktextbox control with a radcombobox to show the items) whose list of items is a list of airports returned from an async call to a WCF service.

The issue that I'm running into is that if I'm typing quickly in the textbox, multiple async calls to get the filtered list of items are kicked off (one for each keypress) and they dont necessarily finish in the same order as they were run - particularly when the list coming back is large.

So if I were to type HPN really quickly, the following calls get kicked off

Async call with H as parameter (#1 - will return 231 rows)
Async call with HP as parameter (#2 - will return 4 rows)
Async call with HPN as parameter (#3 - will rrturn 1 row)

sometimes I'm getting the results to call #1 after the others

I cant change the wcf service I'm calling or add a synchronous method to the WCF service.

Foxpro has a function called CHRSAW which can tell you if there are keys waiting in the input buffer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5skwdb75(v=vs.80).aspx) which could be used to prevent calls #1 and #2 from being called.

Is there an equivalent .NET function/ality that would allow me to do this?

Here's the code I'm using

```
private void ICAO_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txt = (TextBox)sender;

        if (txt.Text != String.Empty)
        {
                radBusyIndicator1.IsBusy = true;
                _ServiceClient.FindAirportByPartialICAOAsync(txt.Text.Trim().ToUpper());
        }
    }
```

Comment: For now, I have found a way: the WCF method has a object UserState parameter, and I'm setting a form DateTime property called _lastAsyncCall setting it to DateTime.Now and passing that as the user state, and then in the completed event, I check if the userstate < _lastAsyncCall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An even easier solution than the one you posted in the comments is to post the text you are sending as the parameter as the user state as well. So when looking for "H" you would pass "H" as the user state.

When the calls come back just only use the one where the user state = the text in the autocomplete.